# Motivation for Derivatives of Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, definition, motivation

> Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb R^n$ with compact support, and $0 < \mu(\mathbb R^n) < \infty$. We define the *lower derivative* and *derivative* of $\mu$ at $x\in \Bbb R^n$ by
> $$\underline{D}(\mu,x) = \liminf_{r\to 0} \frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{\alpha(n)r^n}$$
> and $$D(\mu,x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{\alpha(n)r^n}$$
> respectively, the latter if it exists. Here, $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$.

What is the **motivation** for defining derivatives of measures in the above manner, and how does the above definition relate to the *usual* notion of the derivative in $\mathbb R^n$? Is there a way to *recover* the *"original"* notion of a derivative, from the above definition? I ask since this seems very out of the blue, and not well motivated.

---

Reference: *Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension* by Pertti Mattila.

Comment: The motivation is the same as for derivative in Calculus 101; one wants to see how measures vary locally  with respect to small variations of a baseline measure (Lebegue measure for example). The notion is coincides with what one gets from the fundamental theorem of calculus for measures that absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue. More generally, one can look at the theory of Martingales in probability and/or more general baseline measures too.